# Should I post a question to which I have an answer?

Tags: discussion, questions

Specifically, I was trying to understand abilities like a mule's "beast of burden" and a goliath's "powerful build trait" which both state that the carrying capacity is measured as a "large creature". After doing some research for the answer by flipping pages and using a PDF's search function, I believe I came up with the answer, but am unsure if I understood correctly. To add to it, my history of asking questions without needing edits, negative scores and being put on hold leaves me a little nervous asking...

So before I post it, I would like to ask here if it's worth asking there, here or where can I check my info...

*Note: My main focus is understanding how much weight a mule can carry, though I was confused about their ability.*

**Where should I post a question to verify its information?**

Comment: Are you asking about asking a "check my reasoning" question, or asking the question, answering it yourself, and letting the votes tell you whether you got it right?

Comment: "Check my reasoning" would be most accurate.

Comment: 'Needing edits' isn't a bad thing. Don't let it  discourage you from asking questions. I understand the hesitancy about downvotes, but if you ask a reasonable question and edits fix anything you missed they should get out weighed by up-votes.

Comment: @linksassin Edits aren't bad, though major overhaul edits are embarrassing. What I worry about downvotes and "on hold"s is when the site's info states that too many of those will ban me from posing questions.

Comment: @VictorB You aren't going to get banned for your question going on hold. It's better for it to be on hold while we help you improve it than to get bad answers to a poorly worded question.

Comment: @VictorB If you are concerned though, meta is the right place to ask. You can also drop by the [chat] to ask for help from some experienced users.

Comment: @VictorB you're right that closed and downvoted answers can lead to a question ban. Though I don't have the exact details of the formula to share with you, I can assure you that you're not anywhere near that edge. As of this writing you have 16 questions, 4 of which are deleted or negatively-scored. If that were half or even majority "bad" questions, you might need to worry.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## You have two options

There are two way to ask a question like this. Which you choose probably depends on the specific question and how confident you are in your answer.

#### Is my reading of this rule correct?

Post the question with a title relative to the rule in question. Explain why you were confused and the conclusion you came to. Then ask as the main question "Did I interpret this correctly?" Answers will either affirm your view or show you why it is incorrect. Either way you end up with the correct ruling.

#### Post a question and self answer

Post the question as if you hadn't done the research. Focus on the points that confused you initially and ask for clarification on them. Make this post a good question in its own right.

Then answer that question to the best of your ability in an answer post. Use the research you have done and back up your assumptions. If you are correct you will get upvoted and get a badge for 'self learning'. If not you may get a few downvotes, but other will answer the question correctly and get upvoted in turn.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted the question

Comment: A link to the question, uh, in question: [Am I understanding how to calculate a mule's pulling capacity correctly?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/143519/am-i-understanding-how-to-calculate-a-mules-pulling-capacity-correctly)

Comment: "Post the question as if you hadn't done the research. ... *Make this post a good question in its own right.*" That's the really important part. Sometimes self-answered Q/A's only make sense to the person who thought of the question, so the self-answer could itself be problematic if the original question doesn't make sense outside of the mind of the OP. While writing the question, you have to ask yourself if the Q/A will truly serve other users who aren't you, _and_ you have to make sure you ask the question in a way that others will understand with only the context you give them.